# Coefficient Interpretation

Tags: regression, panel-data, econometrics, interpretation

How would you interpret a panel model regression where the dependent and independent variables of interest are first differenced?

Dependent variable = growth rate of GDP per Capita `d.log(GDPperCapita)`

Independent variable = growth rate of military expenditure as a % of GDP `d.log(militaryexpenditure%ofGDP)`

Both variables are continuous, log transformed and first differenced. As well as this the military expenditure variable is in %, as well then being logged, and then differenced.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the coefficient is positive that means that those two variables tend to move together, and otherwise if negative.

For example, a coefficient of 0.03 means that given a 1% increase in the difference of logarithms of military expenditure as % of GDP you should expect a 0.03% increase in difference of logarithms of GDP per capita (if the intercept is zero).

Comment: thanks, I was more wondering how I would interpret the 0.03 in the equation. 
d.log(GDPperCapita) = a + 0.03(d.log(militaryexpenditure%ofGDP)

i.e. is it saying 1% increase in the growth of military expenditure is associated with a 0.03% point increase in the growth of GDP per Capita?

Comment: Yes, edited that in. You just have to be careful that the coefficience relates increases in the variables *in the units that you used for the regression*. So if you're predicting `d.log(militaryexpenditure%ofGDP)` that's what the increase is on, and that's not to be confused with a percent increase in military expenditure as % of GDP.

Comment: perfect thanks for that - and just to be super specific would it be a 0.03% increase in the difference of logarithms of GDP per capita or a 0.03 percentage point increase in the difference of logarithms of GDP per capita? I ask this as the underlying military expenditure variable is in percentage already, before the two transformations.

Comment: Regression doesn't care what units you're using. Could be percentage points, could be bananas. But whatever units you use to regress are the units you'll get when making predictions. I've edited the answer to contain all the information you need, hopefully. So if `d.log(militaryexpenditure%ofGDP)` increases by a factor of $x$ then `d.log(GDPperCapita)` will increase by a factor of $0.03 x$.